# Find a particular solution for these two differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

1. $y^{''}+2y^{'}+10y=25x^2+3$
2. $y^{''}-3y^{'}+2y=xe^{x}$

I just started learning differential equation... Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208083/finding-the-general-solution-of-a-sixth-degree-differential-equation/208101#208101).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider what kind of functions our solution would be comprised of to give that inhomogeneous part of $25x^2+3$. Have you considered a solution of the form $y=Ax^2+Bx+C$ for the first equation? Use the method of undetermined coefficients.

Use the same approach for the latter. Consider $y=Ax^2e^x+Bxe^x+Ce^x$ since we can figure what will happen when we differentiate with the product rule, e.g.
$$
y=Ax^2e^x+Bxe^x+Ce^x\\y'=Ax^2e^x+(2A+B)xe^x+(B+
C)e^x\\y''=Ax^2e^x+(4A+B)xe^x+(2A+2B+C)e^x
$$

Answer (score 0):

To solve:

1. $y^{''}+2y^{'}+10y=25x^2+3$

I. Consider:

$y^{''}+2y^{'}+10y = 0$

II. Write down the corresponding auxiliary equation:

$m^2 + 2m + 10 = 0$

and solve for $m$ (quadratic formula):

$m = \frac {-2 \pm \sqrt[]{ 4 - 4(1)(10)}}{2}$

$m = -1 \pm3i$

to find your complementary solution $Y_c$.

$Y_c = e^{-t}(\cos3t + \sin3t)$

Recall that our full solution $Y = Y_c + Y_p$.

To solve for $Y_p$ we used the method of "Undetermined Coefficients" which is further explained in this link: http://www.math.uah.edu/howell/DEtext/Part3/Guess_Method.pdf.

For this particular problem, we "guess" a solution that looks like $Ax^2+Bx+C$, because our polynomial $25x^2 + 3$ is of the same form.

III.

$Y_p = Ax^2+Bx+C$ is our guess. Take two derivatives $Y^{\prime}_p,Y^{\prime\prime}_p$, because the DE is second order.

$Y^{\prime}_p = 2Ax+B$

$Y^{\prime\prime}_p = 2A$

Now, plug these derivatives into $y^{''}+2y^{'}+10y=25x^2+3$, and solve the equation for your A, B, C be equating the coefficients that are attached to $x^2,x,\text{constant}$. Plug $A,B,C$ into $Y_p = Ax^2+Bx+C$, and we have our particular solution. Linearly combine with $Y_c$ as $Y = Y_c + Y_p$ and you get the complete solution.

You can use the exact same approach for the second differential equation, but just use $Y_p = (Ax + B)e^x$ as your guess. Note, that for solving second-order non-homogeneous DE's, it is important to understand the different forms that $Y_p$ can be. If you learn the main few (Polynomials, $e^x$'s, and a combination of sines and cosines), then it won't be hard to make the guesses.