# Find general solutions of $y''−y=\frac{2}{1+e^x}$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have solved $y''−y=0$. Solution is $y_c=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}$.
But I don't know how to find a particular solution for $$\displaystyle y''−y=\frac{2}{1+e^x}.$$

Any idea?

Comment: What are your ideas? Is this homework that you are working on? If so, you should denote it as such.

Comment: As I explained last time, consider what types of functions our solution could possibly be made of and use the method of undetermined coefficients to solve for a particular solution. Solve the homogeneous problems and combine your solutions.

Comment: Just to clarify, what do you mean by "As I explained last time"? If this question has been posted in the past day/week, can you link to it?

Comment: Of course we have ideas.  If you want a hint or two, think of a more polite way to phrase your question.  Also include your own attempts to work through the problem.  You won't learn anything by just asking for answers.

Comment: Just look at his user page: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503228/find-a-particular-solution-for-these-two-differential-equations/503231#503231

Comment: sorry for rush to ask the question... details added

Comment: Use $y' = z$ such that $z' = y + {\rm f}\left(x\right)$.

Comment: With $\xi \equiv y' + y\quad$ you'll get a first order equation for $\xi$. Then, solve $y' + y = \xi$ since you already know $\xi$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  To apply the method of undetermined coefficients to any linear nonhomogeneous ODE with constant coefficients, you need to find the annihilator of the function $f(x)$ that appears on the right hand side of the ODE (in standard form).

This can be accomplished by establishing a relation between $f(x)$ and its higher derivatives.  (This is actually one of the ways we construct exam problems!)  Start with the answer $f(x)$ and work backwards.  That is, take higher derivatives to establish a relationship between  $f(x), f'(x), f"(x)$, etc.  Any such relationship describes an ODE for which $f(x)$ is at least a partial solution.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the variation of parameters to obtain the particular solution. The particular solution will be represented by
$$
y_p(x)=g_1(x)y_{1}+g_2(x)y_{2}
$$
where 
$$
g_{1}(x)=-\int \frac{f(x)y_2(x)}{W(x)}dx,~g_2(x)=\int\frac{f(x)y_1(x)}{W(x)}dx 
$$
for $f(x)=\frac{2}{e^x+1}$. The Wronskian of $y_1$ and $y_2$ is given by 
$$
W(x)=\begin{pmatrix}
e^{-x} & e^x \\ 
-e^{-x} & e^x
\end{pmatrix}=2.
$$
Now we can compute the integrals;
$$
g_1(x)=\int \frac{e^x}{e^x+1}dx=-\ln(e^x+1), \\
g_2(x)=\int\frac{1}{e^x(e^x+1)}dx=-e^{-x}+\ln(e^{-x}+1).
$$
Substitute everything into the above formula to get the particular solution.