# Finding a differential equation from $y = (c_1+c_2x)e^x+c_3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to eliminate $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ from $y$.
This is what I've done:
$$y = (c_1+c_2x)e^x+c_3$$
$$y' = (c_1 + c_2(x+1))e^x$$
$$y'' = (c_1 + c_2(x+2))e^x$$
$$y''' = (c_1+c_2(x+3))e^x$$
$$y''' - y'' = c_2e^x \Rightarrow c_2 = \frac{y'''-y''}{e^x}$$
I replaced $c_2$ in the second equation and got $c_1$. Now how can I find $c_3$?

Comment: Generally you use initial conditions to find the values of the constants.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208083/finding-the-general-solution-of-a-sixth-degree-differential-equation/208101#208101).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this way helps you. If we set $D$ as $'$, so we have $Dy=y'$. There are some good points rooted from Calculus telling us: $$(D-a)^2y(x)=D^2y(x)-2aDy(x)+a^2y(x)=y''(x)-2ay'(x)=a^2y(x)$$ and if $y(x)=e^{ax}$ so $(D-a)y(x)=0$ and if $y(x)=C_1+C_2xe^{ax}$ so $$(D-a)^{\color{red}{2}}y(x)=0$$ but clearly $\color{blue}{D}(C_3)=0$ where $C_3$ is any constant. Now consider this one:  $$\color{blue}{D}(D-a)^{\color{red}{2}}=P(D)$$ and apply it on your function $y$. What will you get? Indeed, $P(D)y=0$. Since $$P(D)=D^3-2D^2+D$$ so the desire ODE would be $$y'''-2y''+y'=0$$

Comment: Your final answer helped me to solve it in my own way. I found c1 and c2 from the third and fourth equations and replaced them in the second equation. Thanks.

Comment: @Sajjad: Thanks Mamnunam

Comment: Would you please tell what "$a$" is? The original question doesn't have it. I'm kind of confused...