# Non homogeneous differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the differential equation for
$$
y=c_1e^{2x}\sin x + c_4 e^{2x} \cos x - xe^{-x}.
$$
I'm not sure how to incorporate the last part of the solution into solving this problem?

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208083/finding-the-general-solution-of-a-sixth-degree-differential-equation/208101#208101).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question:** find differential equation for which $y = c_1+c_2x+c_3e^{2x}\cos(x)+c_4e^{2x}\sin(x)-xe^{-x}$ forms the general solution.

**Solution Sketch:** Well, it is fourth order with $\lambda = 0,0,2\pm i$ and so $L=D^2((D-2)^2+1)$ and $L[y]=g$ is the differential equation. Now the question is what is $g$ if $L[-xe^{-x}]=g$? I think you can figure that out if you can differentiate. Yes?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: Glad to help, interesting question.

Comment: This answer refers to the original version of the question.  For some reason, the OP changed the question (removed the first two terms in $y$).

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche indeed, it is for your implicit concern that I added the first two lines to my answer.