# find a 4th order linear, non-homo ODE whose general solution:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to find a fourth order, linear, not homogenous ODE with general solution:

$y=c_1+c_2 x+c_3 e^{2x}\cos x+c_4e^{2x}\sin x-x e^{-x}$?

Is there a specific method? I feel like it is guesswork to a certain degree. I can tell some parts such as the $c_1$ term will originally have had to be some sort of degree $4$ polynomial, and the $\sin,\cos$ terms will be some linear combination  $a\cos +b\sin$ (I think)  as well. but the other ones aren't as obvious to me. Any help would be appreicated. thank you!

Comment: Don't you think that life is sufficiently difficult with ODE's ? You have your solution ! I am just kidding.Interesting problem I shall work. Cheers.

Comment: this is exactly what was asked http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693457/non-homogeneous-differential-equations/693476#693476. Although, the question was changed after it was partially answered by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the solution you know that the characteristic equation of the homogeneous equation has the double root $0$ and the complex conjugate roots $2\pm i$. The characteristic equation is then
$$
r^2((r-2)^2+1)=r^4-4\,r^3+5\,r^2=0.
$$
The equation will be
$$
y''''-4\,y'''+5\,y''=f(x).
$$
You also know that $y=-x\,e^x$ is a solution. Plug it into the equation to find $f$.

Comment: I like this answer, it is essentially the one I gave at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693457/non-homogeneous-differential-equations/693476#693476. That said, to generalize the method we could use the trick to construct the ODE by placing the desired solutions in a determinant which has top row of $y,y', y''$ etc... and the lower rows the same but for the given functions. That gives a method which generalized outside the narrow confines of constant coefficient ODEs where the method of this answer applies.

Answer (score 0):

Leave a constant term on the right hand side, then differentiate.  The first two are easy.

$$y'=c_2+c_5e^{2x}\cos x+c_6e^{2x}\sin x-e^{-x}+xe^{-x}$$

Note that I sort of skipped the trig terms.  I know that the derivative of each is going to be a linear combination of $e^{2x}\cos x$ and $e^{2x}\sin x$, but the exact constants aren't important.

$$y''=c_7e^{2x}\cos x+c_8e^{2x}\sin x+2e^{-x}-xe^{-x}$$

For this specific problem, maybe Julian's method is the best way go from here, solving for $y''$.  If you had no idea what the homogeneous equation looked like, though, the next step would be

$$e^{-2x}\sec xy''=c_7+c_8\tan x+(2-x)e^{-3x}\sec x$$
$$e^{-2x}\sec xy'''+y''(-2e^{-2x}\sec x+e^{-2x}\sec x\tan x)=c_8\sec^2x-e^{-3x}\sec x+(3x-6)e^{-3x}\sec x+(2-x)e^{-3x}\sec x\tan x$$
$$e^{-2x}\cos xy'''+y''(-2e^{-2x}\cos x+e^{-2x}\sin x)=c_8-e^{-3x}\cos x+(3x-7)e^{-3x}\cos x+(2-x)e^{-3x}\sin x$$

Differentiate one last time for the solution.  Divide both sides by the $y^{(4)}$ coefficient if you must.